# React useRef hook with Modal framework

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I am learning to use ReactHooks and needed some help with how I can assign the content of modal to a myRef htmlDivElement.

How can I assign the content of model to the ref element. When I execute it, it comes out empty without any content.  How can I append the contents of Modal to the div?

```
 import React, { FunctionComponent, useRef } from "react";
    import { Modal } from "antd";
    import styles from "./my.module.scss";
    export const myComponent: FunctionComponent= () => {
        const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    
            const DivElement = myRef.current
            Display(DivElement);
    return (
        <div ref={myRef} id="graph_div" className={styles.modal}>
        </div>
      );
    };
    const Display = (
        DivElement: HTMLDivElement | null
      ) => {
DivElement.append  // Somehow I need this to append the Model element
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
      >
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
      </Modal>
    
    };
```

When it renders the id=graph_div has nothing in it. Its empty.
Thanks much